# Extract a String Variable from a Void function

Tags: swift, avfoundation, void

here is my problem :

I would like to recover the variable jan from the Launch App() function and insert it in the override above instead of "Hello there".

```swift
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

            let destVC : troisViewController = segue.destination as! troisViewController

            destVC.dataFromFirst = "Hello there"
        }

        func launchApp(decodedURL: String) -> Void {

            if presentedViewController != nil{
            return
            }

        let jan: String = "\(decodedURL)"
        print(jan)


        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "troissegue", sender: self)
    }
```

The problem is the decoded URL is a barcode obtained by using the camera of my phone, a solution of type : `destVC.dataFromFirst = launchApp()` does not work...

Does Anyone has a similar issue ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: cant you initilize the string variable class level ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to pass the string as `sender` parameter

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
    if segue.identifier == "troissegue" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! troisViewController
        destVC.dataFromFirst = sender as! String
    }
}

func launchApp(decodedURL: String) -> Void {

    if presentedViewController != nil { return }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "troissegue", sender: decodedURL)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was very far from the answer since I could not establish the link between the sender in the override and the sender in the performSegue !